# defaultdict key default value issues

Tags: python, json, defaultdict

I'm new to Python and having an issue with defaultdict.
I have some json, where the lastInspection key isn't always present. I need to put a default value in for the date.

`p.get("lastInspection", "")` returns me `{'date': '2018-01-03'}`

```
problem = [{'lastInspection': {'date': '2018-01-03'}, 'contacts': []}]

for p in problem:
    print(p.get("lastInspection", ""))
    print(p.get("date", ""))
```

Comment: It's not clear what question you're trying to ask us, or how defaultdict is supposed to be involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing, that the defaultdict is not what you want to use.

Default values should be declared in the second argument of the `get` method.

```
problem = [{'lastInspection': {'date': '2018-01-03'}, 'contacts': []}]
default_inspection = { 'date': '2018-01-03' }

for p in problem:
    # default_inspection is returned, when 'lastInspection' is not present in the json
    inspection = p.get("lastInspection", default_inspection)
    print(inspection)
    # now you access date, as you are sure, that it is present
    print(inspection['date'])
```

Comment: many thanks Marek Wawrzos this works perfectly! wouldn't have thought to use default values.